# Improve current recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, closures

I am working to improve recursion skills, and took a crack at the recursive function below.

However, I'm looking to improve the implementation (and thus my understanding) by eliminating the necessity of the `i` iterator as a second parameter to `correcter`. I feel like the function as is at the moment is still very iterative, if that makes sense.

How would I go about specifically eliminating this from the function, and still use use a recursive function to run the same operation successfully?

Thanks!

```js
// Transform an array of items, correcting gramatically 

var capitals = ["MaDRid", "paRIs", "SantIAgO"]

var correcter = function(array, i) {

  var transform = function(city) {
   return city.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + city.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  }
    
  // base case 
  if (array.length === i) {
   return array;
  }

  // action 
  array[i] = transform(array[i]);

  // recursive case
  return correcter(array, i + 1);
};

correcter(capitals, 0);
```

Comment: It is not a very good use case for using recursion, even as a study object. You have a list of items and a known length. Would have been different if it was about processing nested arrays or something like that. This just begs for using `Array#map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass in an array, with each level passing in one less of the array. When the array is empty, return. `concat` will take care of adding or not adding anything to the resulting array (`concat` does nothing if you concat an empty array).

```js
var capitals = ["MaDRid", "paRIs", "SantIAgO"]

function correcter(array){

  var city = array[0];
  if(!city) return [];
  var correctedCity = city.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + city.slice(1).toLowerCase();

  return [correctedCity].concat(correcter(array.slice(1)));
}

var corrected = correcter(capitals);

document.write(JSON.stringify(corrected));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here how you can make i optional. If i is not passed then we start from 0. if it's passed then we use it to traverse. Also take transform out of the recursive function this way it's defined only ones.

```
var capitals = ["MaDRid", "paRIs", "SantIAgO"]

function transform (city) {
  return city.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + city.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
function correcter (array, i) {
  if ( i == null) { // <- i is optional now
    i = 0;
  }

  // base case 
  if (array.length === i) {
    return array;
  }

  // action 
  array[i] = transform(array[i]);

  // recursive case
  return correcter(array, i + 1);
};
```